# Maximizing a function using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy

everyone! As the title states, I am trying to **maximize** the value of a multivariate scalar function using the scipy.optimize.minimize functionality. As per the documentation, one is required to set the **sign variable** in the function and the Jacobian (and if necessary the Hessian) to **-1** for this purpose. 
However, as a result of this, my final result for the objective function output ends up being **negative**. I tried the most basic hack to figure out what was going wrong by printing out the objective function evaluation inside the function itself. Surprisingly, the **actual output turned out to be positive**, while that **returned by minimize() was negative**. 
Has anyone here faced a similar situation and, if so, what would you propose should be done to correct this error? Would be grateful if you could throw a little light on the importance of the sign factor in the process.
P.S. I have been using **SLSQP method** for optimization.

Comment: Your result is negative because you multiplied your objective function by -1. Just multiply the result by -1 again to get the value of your original objective function.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, that solves everything. But is it something that we need to do everytime we maximize an objective function using scipy.optimize?

Comment: Please provide a complete and minimal code example. The output you describe could have *any* reason, including typos when calling `print`. Also,  what is a *sign variable* and where did you find this documented? The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) never mentions the word *sign*.

Comment: My apologies for the trouble. Well, it is mentioned as a part of the [scipy.optimize documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html), under the topic: Constrained minimization of multivariate scalar functions. It'll be great if you could take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's something that's commonly done every time. The `sign` parameter in the link you provided is not part of the `minimize` API. Rather, it's just an extra constant parameter passed to the user-defined OF and the gradient (through the argument `args=(-1.0,)`), which is doing nothing more than multiplying these functions by -1.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much for your help!